# Get current logged in Windows Users privilliges

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-7, windows-vista

I have to get current user privileges before opening my main application screen.
As I want to make sure only administrator user(in Standalone PC) is using the application.
I have tried following code and it is not working on Windows 7 (not tried in XP and other yet).

```
Dim identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
Dim principal = New WindowsPrincipal(identity)
Dim isElevated As Boolean = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
Return isElevated
```

Is there any other class of function I need to refer. It' been a long time and I'm not sure what is wrong. Please help. I need it work on Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, and if possible on Windows 8 too.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet is working for me in Windows7. Can you please try it out. Thanks

```
public static bool IsAdminUser()
{
     bool isAdmin = false;
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
     WindowsPrincipal principal = (WindowsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
     WindowsIdentity identity = (WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity;
     isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
     return isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not worked on my VB.NET. Is it working for default admin or a user promoted as admin